# An easy way to make GONE animation work

Tags: android, animation

I have a custom search panel, which is a part of main layout. Most of time the panel is hidden. I would like to add appearing/disappearing animation to the panel. Here is the simplified layout excerpt:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editSearch"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <<Other inner views to be animated>>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <<Other views, which should not be affected by the animation>>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Try 1**: I added animation resources and attach them to the @id/layoutSearch with this line in XML:

```
android:layoutAnimation="@anim/search_in_layout"
```

anim/search_in.xml:

```
<translate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator"
    android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

anim/search_in_layout.xml:

```
<layoutAnimation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:animation="@anim/search_in" />
```

The animation works fine, but only for the panel appearing. The panel disappears in a moment without animation when I hide it with:

```
mSearchLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

**Try 2**: I guess the above solution does not work as the animation destination parameters match the current panel position. OK, I created two more animation resources: anim/search_out.xml and anim/search_out_layout.xml. The only differences are exchanged "fromYDelta" and "toYDelta" values and updated "android:animation" value. Then I load the resources in the code and set them to the @id/layoutSearch like this:

```
LayoutAnimationController controller =
    AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(this, R.anim.search_out_layout);
mSearchLayout.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
```

The "out" animation triggered on calling of setLayoutAnimation(). After the animation the search panel returns to it original position on the screen it had before "out" animation. If I try to call mSearchLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE) just after setLayoutAnimation(), I see no animation, the panel disappears at once.

**Try 3**: I guess I need to create the animation in the code and then set a listener on it. Then I should call mSearchLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE) in the onAnimationEnd() handler to hide the panel after the animation played. I did not tried this yet. I think it's over complicated.

I guess I missed something important. Is there a way to implement GONE animation a bit easy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Try 3: I guess I need to create the animation in the code and then set a listener on it. Then I should call mSearchLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE) in the onAnimationEnd() handler to hide the panel after the animation played. I did not tried this yet. I think it's over complicated.

That's what you should do and actually that's not hard to achieve.

Sample code:

```
public class YourClass extends Foo implements AnimationListener {

    //...

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation a) {
        // Do stuff.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation a) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation a) {
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems, there is no easier way to make "out" animation work. Thank you.

Comment: I wonder if you've found a way to do this without the annoying flash at the end of the animation, when the view lays itself out again because the view is GONE.

Comment: Adding a constructor to this to take a View as an argument is a nice way to not have to repeat code a million times.   Then you can just apply it to whatever you want with a.setAnimationListener(new MyAnimationListener(v)); , as long as each animation is only tied to a single view of course.

Answer (score 7):

To follow on to the answers above :   here is how I solved this problem.

Please note that setting **setFillBefore** and **setFillAfter** in your animation will lead to the following bug!  [Issue 5272: View with visibility View.GONE still generates touch events
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5272](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5272)

***File :*** MyWebViewActivity.java

```
private View mBottomOverlay;
private View mTopOverlay;
private boolean mControlsOverlayVisible;
private Animation mSlideBottomUpAnimation;
private Animation mSlideBottomDownAnimation;
private Animation mSlideTopDownAnimation;
private Animation mSlideTopUpAnimation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reader_layout);

    // load the overlay resources
    mTopOverlay = findViewById(R.id.reader_overlay_top_toolbar);
    mBottomOverlay = findViewById(R.id.reader_overlay_bottom_toolbar);

    initAnimations();
}

private void initAnimations() {

    final AnimationListener makeTopGone = new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onAnimationEnd - makeTopGone");
            mTopOverlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    };

    final AnimationListener makeBottomGone = new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onAnimationEnd - makeBottomGone");
            mBottomOverlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    };

    final AnimationListener makeTopVisible = new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onAnimationStart - makeTopVisible");
            mTopOverlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {}
    };

    final AnimationListener makeBottomVisible = new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onAnimationStart - makeBottomVisible");
            mBottomOverlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {}
    };

    mSlideTopUpAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_top_up);
    mSlideBottomDownAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_bottom_down);
    mSlideTopUpAnimation.setAnimationListener(makeTopGone);
    mSlideBottomDownAnimation.setAnimationListener(makeBottomGone);

    mSlideTopDownAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_top_down);
    mSlideBottomUpAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_bottom_up);
    mSlideTopDownAnimation.setAnimationListener(makeTopVisible);
    mSlideBottomUpAnimation.setAnimationListener(makeBottomVisible);
}

private void hideControlOverlays() {
    Log.d(TAG, "hideControlOverlays");
    mTopOverlay.startAnimation(mSlideTopUpAnimation);
    mBottomOverlay.startAnimation(mSlideBottomDownAnimation);
    mControlsOverlayVisible = false;
}

private void showControlOverlays() {
    Log.d(TAG, "showControlOverlays");
    mTopOverlay.startAnimation(mSlideTopDownAnimation);
    mBottomOverlay.startAnimation(mSlideBottomUpAnimation);
    mControlsOverlayVisible = true;
}
```

***File :*** /res/layout/reader_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/reader_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/reader_overlay_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/reader_overlay_top_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:background="#80000000" >

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar_top" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/reader_overlay_bottom_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#80000000"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar_bottom_left" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**File :** /res/anim/slide_bottom_down.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" >
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="100%" />
</set>
```

**File :** /res/anim/slide_bottom_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" >
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0" />
</set>
```

**File :** /res/anim/slide_top_down.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" >
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0" />
</set>
```

**File :** /res/anim/slide_top_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" >
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="-100%" />
</set>
```

Comment: Can you tell me when you call when/where you call the functions hideControlOverlays() and showControlOverlays() ? I am trying to develop something similar. Your answer will be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: you can call the showControlsOverlay() method for instance from an onTouch or onClick listener on a view.  The hideControlsOverlay() method can be called from another onTouch or onClick handler, or you can set up a delayed runnable to call it after a few seconds to automatically dismiss the overlay without user interaction.

Answer (score 4):

you need to call **setFillAfter()** of Animation Class to hold the animation after playing.

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutSearch);
Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.push_down);
a=setFillAfter(true); 
layout.setLayoutAnimation(new LayoutAnimationController(a));
layout.startLayoutAnimation();
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting a View to `GONE` effectively removes it from the layout. Instead you should set it to `INVISIBLE`, and then `GONE` after the animation has completed if you need to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to set INVISIBLE. Seems, there is no point to do it. One still need to setup layout animation and the listener in the code. Animation starts on setLayoutAnimation(), no need to set INVISIBLE. This very strange for me, as "in" animation does not require a single line of code...

Comment: this way work for **View** show or hide, I don't think **ViewGroup** work as well, but thanks Joseph-Earl provide it.