# Animate a dynamic number of Views and then set them invisible/gone

Tags: android, animation

In an Activity, I am retrieving data from a server. There are a limited number of `TableRow`s containing further Views pre defined in the layout xml file, all set to `android:visibility="gone"`. Further there's an array in the java class with all IDs of these `TableRow`s.
For each entering "data entry", I fill such a `TableRow`, set it visible and animate it (the animation is a 'push in' from a randomly choosen vertical side). As an further hint, which is important later in this question, every data packet retrieving from the server is related to a month.

Whenever I get data, I do following process

1. Fill the still invisible `TableRow`s with the information
2. For every time step 1 is executed, a value in a boolean array is set to `true`
3. call `showAnimation()`
4. for every entry that is true in the boolean array, get `TableRow` at index `i` in the id array, set an Animation and set visibility to visible

This works fine. Even if the visibility is set before starting the Animation, it doesn't matter, since this takes so few time, that the Animation has already begun in our eyes.

Now comes the problem: the reverse way doesn't work. Let me clarify: I want, that the `TableRow`s are pushed out of the window, and THEN set to invisible resp. gone whenever I change the actual month, and the new entries are pushed then in. The problem is, that as soon the Animation starts, the `View`s are set to invisible / gone. I tried to solve this with an `AnimationListener` like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591686/an-easy-way-to-make-gone-animation-work) in the first answer. This leads to two possible ways:

1. Define such an `AnimationListener` for each `TableRow` and set the visibility in the `onAnimationEnd()`. I find this is very ugly, since it is not dynamical.
2. Have access to a kind of index in the `AnimationListener` and set the same Listener to every `TableRow`'s Animation. **Here I don't know how possibly solve this**. As I discovered earlier, setting Animations on `View`s set in a loop (a for loop in my case) results in the Animations beeing started when the loop has finished, and not whenever it is set. So even if I would carry a global index variable in that for loop to be used in the `onAnimationEnd()`, it obviously would came to nothing.

Do someone knows a better way to implement this? Solving it with a `Handler.postDelayed()` does not do the trick, since it is possible that the new data has already come from the server, and therefor the new entries are already visible (and thus the new ones are set to invisible).

Comment: while I'm thinking here on a good answer to give you. Tell me something, why are you using Table and TableRows instead of List and an adapter?

Comment: Because I felt more free in designing issues by using a Table.

Comment: it just seemed that a Adapter is most suitable by variable data coming from a server. But I can see how some of the table feature might be interesting for the visual part.

Answer (score 1):

ok I thought a lot about it and honestly I agree with you that it's not the nicest way, but due to the framework limitations the 1st way is still the best one.

It will be nice if we could from the listener call back do:

```
public void onAnimationEnd (Animation animation){
    animation.getView().setVisibility(View.Visible);
}
// but this doesn't exist.
```

Just make sure every time you're setting an animation to start to do:

```
Animation anim = row.getAnimation()
if(anim!=null){
     anim.setListener(null); // to avoid the listener to be called
     anim.cancel(); // to stop it from running
}
// and then go ahead and setup a new animation with new listener
anim = new MyAnimation();
anim.setListener(new SetToInvisibleListener());
row.startAnimation(anim);
```